# EntityFieldQuery: number of field values as condition

Tags: database

I have a node type which has a field that can contain an unlimited amount of images.

I want to retrieve a set of entities, but only entities that contain at least one image.

So far this is my query:

```
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'reference')
    ->propertyCondition('promote', 1)
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->pager(12)
    ->execute();
```

How should I use the extra fieldCondition to indicate I only want nodes with at least 1 value for field_images?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like stating the obvious but you need to count the number of values in 'field_images', then you can set the condition to check that result and make sure it is greater than 0.

There's a good overview of adding expressions and conditions with the `count()` function on [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33609/how-to-write-a-drupal-7-query-with-count-and-having-properties).

You'll also need to perform a join between 'node' and the table that holds your field values before you make your count, something like [this](https://api.drupal.org/comment/56558#comment-56558):

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_images', 'fi', 'n.nid = fi.nid');
...rest of query
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a **propertyCondition** for this.
A code like:

```
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'reference')
    ->propertyCondition('promote', 1)
    ->propertyCondition('field_images', 1)
    ->propertyOrderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->pager(12)
    ->execute();
```

-would help. But I don't know whether it works with 'node' 'entity_type'.

If not, please comment below and/or edit this answer.

Thank you.